# limit result upon sum of two column

Tags: php, mysql

Table:

```
id | c1  | c2
-------------    
1  | 10 | 20
2  | 55 | 20
3  | 30 | 30
4  | 11 | 80
5  | 12 | 20
```

and query

```
select (sum(c1)+sum(c2))as sum from mytable where sum > 100 ??
```

the above generates an error as sum not part of the table. any work around to limit / where condition to restrict result returned to be only upon this condition of two columns sum ? (with out the need to add a third column to the table)

Thank you

Comment: Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` also `sum` is probably reserved, try another field name.

Comment: @Orbling (surprisingly?!) sum is not a reserved word.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: It is surprising! It's not in the [reserved word list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) - but I would still not use it, could become reserved in future and confusing in any event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `HAVING` clause.

So,

```
SELECT (SUM(c1)+SUM(C2)) AS sum FROM mytable HAVING sum > 100;
```

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Agreed. Truth be told, I'm not sure the point of this query to begin with.  That is, this query would make much more sense if it was `SELECT (c1+c2) AS sum FROM mytable...`, as a sum per row. But that wasn't what the question was.

Comment: and assume i want to add a where condition to be where id > 5 for example ?

Comment: HEY ahmed checkout my answer at bottom regarding id > 5 question

Answer (score 2):

You can either wrap your existing query in another select:

```
select total
from
(
  select sum(c1 + c2) as total 
  from mytable 
) d
where total > 100;
```

Or you can use a HAVING cluase:

```
select sum(c1 + c2) as total 
from mytable 
having sum(c1 + c2) > 100;  -- you can also use the total alias in the having
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a908/6).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is related to Ahmed's comment:

```
SELECT (c1+c2) AS sum FROM mytable WHERE ID > 5  GROUP BY ID HAVING sum > 100;
```